# UPDATE table with information from 2 other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables with info as follows:

**NOEUDS:**

```
NOEUD   TYPE_MAT   NUM_COL
1        PBT         100
2        AMP         
3        REP    
4        PBP         120
```

**COLINFO:**

```
NUM_COL    INTEREXTER
100            1
120            2
```

**PB:**

```
NOEUD     FORFAIT
1           I
3            
4           E
```

I would like to update table PB.forfait with an E when in colinfo.num_col = 2 for example.

I'm trying something like this, but still did not manage to succeed.
It is a Microsoft Access database.

```
UPDATE pb

inner join (

SELECT noeud, type_mat, n.num_col, c.interexter
FROM noeuds AS n, colinfo AS c
WHERE ((NOEUDS.TYPE_MAT="PBT") Or (NOEUDS.TYPE_MAT="PBP")) 
  And (n.num_col=c.num_col)

) n on pb.noeud=n.noeud

SET (PB.FORFAIT = "E")

WHERE (n.INTEREXTER="2");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Comment: @jordeu sql is a generic tag and SQL Server solutions are often not suitable for MS Access questions.

Comment: @Remou the answer of those question give the solution for ANSI, MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle.

Comment: @jordeu But not MS Access (Jet/ACE) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE (PB 
INNER JOIN Noeuds ON PB.NOEUD = Noeuds.NOEUD) 
INNER JOIN ColInfo ON Noeuds.NUM_COL = ColInfo.NUM_COL 
SET PB.FORFAIT = "E"
WHERE (((ColInfo.INTEREXTER)=2));
```

I built this using the query design window, a very useful tool in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE 
(NOEUDS AS n INNER JOIN COLINFO AS ci ON n.NUM_COL = ci.NUM_COL) 
INNER JOIN PB ON n.NOEUD = PB.NOEUD 
SET PB.FORFAIT = "E"
WHERE (n.TYPE_MAT="PBP" Or n.TYPE_MAT="PBT") 
  AND ci.INTEREXTER=2
```

If `ci.INTEREXTER` is a string then use

```
AND ci.INTEREXTER = "2"
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. I'm getting syntax error on (pb.NOEUD = n.NOEUD
                       AND (pb.TYPE_MAT = 'PBT' OR pb.TYPE_MAT = 'PBB')
    INNER JOIN COLINFO ci ON n.NUM_COL = ci.NUM_COL
                         AND ci.INTEREXTER = "2"
SET pb.FORFAIT = "E"). it says operator is missing. :S

Comment: The tag says MS Access so that will not run. For one, you need to add some parentheses on those joins.

Comment: In M$ Access UPDATE / FROM do not work. PB is a complete table name.

Comment: Thanks Marco, the  first attempt worked with the right parenthesis. Thanks very much for your help. This one works fine :P